# Can this be solved in quadractic form?

Tags: exponential-function, quadratic-forms

An equation with exponentials and would like to rewrite for x.

$f= \frac{-1}{(10^{x-a}+1)(10^{x-b}+1)}$

$\frac{-1}{f}= {(10^{x-a}+1)(10^{x-b}+1)}$

f, a, b are known values and can variate. And plugin some values for it, results in following form, e.g.

$\frac{-1}{f}= {(10^{x-9.35}+1)(10^{x-5.22}+1)}$

$\frac{-10^0}{f}= {(10^{x-9.35}+10^0)(10^{x-5.22}+10^0)}$

$\frac{-10^0}{f}= {(10^{2x-9.35-5.22} + 10^{x-9.35} + 10^{x-5.22} + 10^0)}$

$\frac{-10^0}{f}= {(10^{2x-9.35-5.22} + 10^{x-9.35} + 10^{x-5.22} + 10^0)}$

${1 = -f(10^{2x-9.35-5.22} + 10^{x-9.35} + 10^{x-5.22} + 10^0)}$

${0 = -f*10^{2x-9.35-5.22} -f*10^{x-9.35} -f*10^{x-5.22} -f*10^0 -1}$

${0 = 10^{2x-4.12} +10^{x-9.35} +10^{x-5.22} +10^0 +\frac{1}{f}}$

I tried to look at it in terms of quadratic form. However it doesn't seem right.

I would like some help to rewrite the equation for x using f, a, b and then solve for x?

Comment: Let $10^x=y$ and expand

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici is there a way to take log of both sides?

Comment: No.$\mathstrut$

Answer (score 1):

Start from
$$-1/f = (10^{x-a} + 1)(10^{x-b}+1).$$
To turn this into a quadratic equation, we define the substitution $y = 10^x$. Then we have
$$-1/f = (10^{-a}y+1)(10^{-b}y +1)$$
and expanding this gives
$$-1/f = 10^{-(a+b)}y^2 + (10^{-a} + 10^{-b})y + 1.$$
We can now apply the quadratic formula for $y$, noting that by the definition of $y$, it is positive, so we only take the positive solution (if it exists). This gives
$$y = \frac{-(10^{-a} + 10^{-b}) + \sqrt{(10^{-a} +10^{-b})^2 - 4 \times 10^{-(a+b)} \times (1 + 1/f)}}{2 \times 10^{-(a+b)}}.$$
Then, we invert the substitution to get $x = \log_{10}(y)$, again noting that for certain values of $a, b$ and $f$, a solution for $x$ may not exist. For example, if $f$ is positive, as the right hand side of the initial equation is always negative, a solution will not exist. In fact, the right hand side is always between $-1$ and $0$, so $f$ needs to lie in the interval $(-1, 0)$ for there to be a solution.

Comment: Your approach is simple and helpful. What if $f$ must be between (-2, 2)?